# Listen for a tab click in tab control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm struggling to figure out how to know when user clicks a certain tab button in windows form application.

At the moment I have following set up (Form1.Designer.cs):

```
//Adding click event handler to desired tab
this.tabStartPageView.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.tabStartPageView_Click);
```

And in my Form1.cs file:

```
private void tabStartPageView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Click Tested");
}
```

But nothing happens when I click on a tab, console only writes "Click Tested" when I click within window area associated to the tab.

**EDIT:** The reason I need to know this is so I can get data from an xml file on tab click and dynamically build its view depending on it.

I have tried:

```
if(tabControlViews.SelectedTab == tabStartPageView)
{
    //do something
}
```

But I get error saying: [APP NAME] is a 'field' but is used like a 'type' ...\Form1.cs

Comment: Clicking on a tab will change the selected tab? can you try the `selectedindexchanged` or `tabindexchanged` event

Comment: @huMptyduMpty clicking on a tab should trigger some checks based on those I want to build tab view / window associated with that clicked tab. Can you please expand on suggestions you provided? Still new to this :)

Comment: Ok, you have a answer now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement it as below suggetion in Form Constructor

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();    
  Tabs.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(Tabs_SelectedIndexChanged);
}
```

and than implement it

```
void Tabs_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e) {
  if (e.TabPage == TaskListPage) {

  }
}
```

Comment: I'm having an issue to understand how to implement it correctly, can you define if "Tabs", "Tabs_SelectedIndexChanged", "TabPage" and "TaskListPage" should be changed to suit my element naming or some of them remain as is? and how is "Tab_Selected" method triggered? Sorry if it's something obvious, I'm just confused.

Comment: On Selected event handler you can cast the sender to the proper control and check for it's name. If the event is generated from TabPage2 you can fire the key event. Its Fired whenever you change the Tabpage1 to TabPage2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Handle TabControl SelectedIndexChanged event as follows:

```
 private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages["tabPage1"])
     {
         MessageBox.Show("tabPage1");
     }
     // And so on....
 }
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how to trigger this method, I renamed variables and it seems to be correct, yet whenever I test it nothing happens, so I guess it needs to be triggered somehow?